# Amazon AWS - python for beginners

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, python-multithreading

I have a computationally intensive program doing calculations that I intend to parallelise. It is written in python and I hope to use the [`multiprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module. I would like some help with understanding what I would need to do to have one program run from my laptop controlling the entire process.

I have two options in terms of what computers I can use. One is computers which I can access through `ssh user@comp1.com` from the terminal ( not sure how to access them through python ) and then run the instance there, although I'd like a more programmatic way to get to them than that. It seems that if I ran [a remote manager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-remote-manager) type application it would work?

The second option I was thinking is utilising AWS E2C servers. (I think that is what I need). And I found [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto) which I've never used but seemed to provide an interface to control the AWS system. I feel that I would then need something to actually distribute jobs on AWS, probably similarly as option 1 (?). I'm a bit in the dark here.

EDIT:

To give you an idea of how parallelisable it is:

```
res = []
for param in Parameters:
    res.append(FunctionA(param))
Parameters2 = FunctionB(res)
res2 = []
for param in Parameters2:
    res2.append(FunctionC(param))
return res, res2
```

So the two loops are basically where I can send off many `param` values to be run in parallel and I know how to recombine them to create `res` as long as I know which `param` they came from. Then I need to group them all together to get `Parameters2` and then the second part is again parallelisable.

Comment: What do you define as a "computationally intensive calculation"? Premature optimization is a common mistake. If you are interested in multi-threading why not try Python's [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#module-threading) class first? Even laptops these days come with multiple cores and can do a lot of calculation.

Comment: I'm doing 100, 4 x 4 matrix multiplications  ~ 1e7 times, I'm not even sure if I'll be able to do it on multicore but trying to give it a try

Comment: Also, I thought threading doesn't use more cores because of GIL

Comment: you are right, threading will not help you here. the approach that I crudely described below would be your starting point.

Comment: @remudada and evan54, my mistake. As I am still new to Python I was not aware of the GIL, so thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would want to use the multiprocess module only if you want the processes to share data in memory. That is something I would recommend ONLY if you absolutely have to have shared memory due to performance considerations. python multiprocess applications are non-trivial to write and debug.

If you are doing something like the distributed.net or seti@home projects, where even though the tasks are computationally intenive they are reasonably isolated, you can follow the following process.

1. Create a master application that would break down the large task into smaller computation chunks (assuming that the task can be broken down and the results then can be combined centrally).
2. Create python code that would take the task from the server (perhaps as a file or some other one time communication with instructions on what to do) and run multiple copies of these python processes
3. These python processes will work independently from each other, process data and then return the results to the master process for collation of results.

you could run these processes on AWS single core instances if you wanted, or use your laptop to run as many copies as you have cores to spare.

*EDIT: Based on the updated question*

So your master process will create files (or some other data structures) that will have the parameter info in them. As many files as you have params to process. This files will be stored in a shared folder called needed-work

Each python worker (on AWS instances) will look at the needed-work shared folder, looking for available files to work on  (or wait on a socket for the master process to assign the file to them).

The python process that takes on a file that needs work, will work on it and store the result in a separate shared folder with the the parameter as part of the file structure.

The master process will look at the files in the work-done folder, process these files and generate the combined response

This whole solution could be implemented as sockets as well, where workers will listen to sockets for the master to assign work to them, and master will wait on a socket for the workers so submit response.

The file based approach would require a way for the workers to make sure that the work they pick up is not taken on by another worker. This could be fixed by having separate work folders for each worker and the master process would decided when there needs to be more work for the worker.

Workers could delete files that they pick up from the work folder and master process could keep a watch on when a folder is empty and add more work files to it.

Again more elegant to do this using sockets if you are comfortable with that.

Comment: I think that would work, the only catch is that I need to get everything together for an intermediate step. I edited the question to show you what I mean

Comment: Thank you for the response! I was wondering if you could provide any insight in how I can control the AWS processes from my laptop, or should I post this in a different question? ideally through python

Comment: A separate question would be appropriate, because you would need to use the web services for that. I can tell you it's easily possible though.