# how to create a single python file from dependencies

Tags: python

I would like to create a single file from python with dependencies only on python modules, such as numpy, sys etc

The manual way of doing this is looking at each import and copy->paste whatever it is importing at that location and delete the `import` command. Is there a way to do this faster/quicker either programmatically or through eclipse/pydev?

I thought maybe the pyc file would do that but that didn't work.

Thank you

EDIT:

File1.py

```
def foo(arg1, arg2):
    return arg1 + arg2**arg1
```

File2.py

```
import sys

from File1 import foo

arg1 = sys.argv[1]
arg2 = sys.argv[2]

print foo(arg1, arg2)
```

NewSingleFile.py Notice that now instead of the `from bla import bla` I have the definition

```
import sys

def foo(arg1, arg2):
    return arg1 + arg2**arg1

arg1 = sys.argv[1]
arg2 = sys.argv[2]

print foo(arg1, arg2)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `looking at each import and copy->paste whatever it is importing at that location` and by `delete the import command`?

Comment: I edited the question to give an example of what I mean, hopefully it is clears up what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately — at least in the general case — this isn't trivial, since many modules (especially NumPy, etc) are not pure Python code, so inlining them would be very difficult.

For specific situations where all the imports are pure Python, it would be possible to use some combination of the AST module (to parse the code) and "eval" (to run the code). Something like this:

```
import foo
```

Would be transformed into:

```
foo_module = types.ModuleType("foo")
exec """# this is foo.py …""" in foo_module.__dict__
sys.modules["foo"] = foo_module
import foo
```

Comment: wait I think this is the wrong way round. I'm trying to do this with modules I wrote not with the python modules. ie `from ModIWrote import fooIwrote` becomes `def fooIwrote(): etc`

Comment: I also get an error saying: `type object 'type' has no attribute 'ModuleType'`

Comment: Err, sorry, should be `types.ModuleType`

Comment: Also, exactly what you want *is* (sort of) possible in theory, but would be *very* fiddly to get right… what's your motivation for doing this?

Comment: I'm trying to create a parallel programming type situation where on each machine (could be AWS servers) I just want to have a single file that needs to run rather than a complex tree of files. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23186701/aws-server-starting-and-managing-through-python and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23166177/amazon-aws-python-for-begginers

Comment: Ah… well, in that case, trying to inline things is not the right solution (esp. because numpy and friends absolutely won't work). Better would be to create a virtual environment on one AWS server, tar that, then copy and extract it on the other servers.

Comment: I'm still very confused as to the solution you provided. what is in the `"""# this is foo.py …"""`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51065/discussion-between-evan54-and-david-wolever)